# use nexus-prisma without prisma client

Tags: node.js, graphql, prisma, nexus-prisma, nexus-js

I am planning on using prisma for building the database and migrations, I am not going to use prisma client as there are some limitations I am hitting since prisma does not use native joins. I also want to use nexus prisma to auto generate types for my graphql api. However, I see that each time I do `npx prisma generate`, prisma client is also auto generated. I am using google cloud to deploy my project and plan to use `cloudbuild.yml` with one of the steps being to apply prisma migrations and compile ts to js.

I want to get rid of the extra prisma stuff that I do not need but I am not sure to go about it. Would I copy `nexus-prisma` in `node_modules` to my final build? Run `npm remove ...`?

I have tried the following:

Uninstalled `@prisma/client` but nexus-prisma depends on it.

removed `generate client` from `schema.prisma` but got an error that `nexus-prisma` relies on generate client